# Access current chrome document

Tags: c#, google-chrome, siebel

I would like to be able to access a chrome window's currently loaded page without using debug mode.  Is there anything similar in Chrome?  My end game is to be able to communicate with Siebel Open UI via javascript.  For IE, I can use code similar to the code below and have it working.

I did come across a post that mentioned Selenium, but is it possible to do it without any additional products?  The company I work for is adverse to adding new products into the enviroment.

```
foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ieInst in new SHDocVw.ShellWindowsClass())
{
    var document = ieInst.Document as HTMLDocument;
    ...
}
```

Thanks for any help